# MySQL запрос один ко многим

Tags: mysql

Друзья, помогите составить MySQL запрос.
Есть таблица с продуктом product.

| id | model |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Товар |

Есть таблица с параметрами parameters

| id_product | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | параметр 1 |
| 1 | параметр 2 |
| 1 | параметр 3 |

Возможно ли составить запрос, что бы получить в результате

```
products[
 [1] => [
  id => 1,
  model => "Товар",
  parameters => [
   0 => [id_product => 1, val => параметр 1],
   1 => [id_product => 1, val => параметр 2],
   2 => [id_product => 1, val => параметр 3],
  ]
 ]
]
```

Comment: SQL выдает в итоге запроса строго прямоугольную таблицу, без вложенностей. Поэтому результат не может быть таким как показан в вопросе. Либо делаете обычный join который приводит к "дублированию" данных первой таблицы и делаете преобразование в нужную вам структуру на клиенте. Либо после такого join делаете group by и собираете parameters с помощью group_concat в одну строку, которую преобразуете в массив опять же на клиенте

Comment: можно использовать 2 запроса, если сценарий использования позволяет.

Comment: @Mike Спасибо! Это исчерпывающий ответ.